# Losing Magento Session

Tags: magento-1.9, session, cookie, customer-session, timeout

I've been getting informed that occasionally when our receptionist is taking orders over the phone on our **Magento ver. 1.9** website, her basket is randomly emptying itself.

I've been unable to replicate the issue myself but I've noticed our cookie lifetime is set to **3600** (*1 hour*).

Because our receptionist is on the website all day every day, am I right in believing that every hour that she's on the website she will lose her cookie and this could be what is causing the problem?

Or would Magento detect that she is still on the website and keep the cookie active?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie lifetime will refresh and set to be active for the next one hour. In other words if the web page is not active for more than an hour then session will lost as result cart will be cleared.

 There are many ways to get it fixed.

- To increase cookie / session time value to retain the cart for long time or to a reasonable time as per the requirement. This will be a easy win, just set the time from magento admin.
- You can ask your representative to login and add product to vart. So just login will help and you get traceability.